# How to, using the definiton of a limit, calculate the limit, if it exists in the first place, of the sequence $ a_{n} = \frac{n + 1}{3n - 4} $?

Tags: real-analysis

I've been taught how to evaluate limits in high school, so I know that the limit of the sequence  $ a_{n} = \frac{n + 1}{3n - 4} $ is $ \frac{1}{3} $, but I have no idea how to show that using only the definition of a limit. This is pretty much the first time that I've been exposed to these types of "proof-problems", where, to solve the problem, you have to do more than just manipulate numbers whilst obeying the rules that the teacher had given me, so any kind of help, in whatever form, is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$ you can find $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n > n_0 \implies |a_n - \frac 13| < \epsilon$

So now let's see what the equation on the right looks like. (To avoid any inconvinience with negative numbers you can consider $n \ge 2$). Then we have:

$$a_n - \frac 13 = \frac{n+1}{3n-4} - \frac 13 = \frac{3n+3 - 3n+4}{3(3n-4)} = \frac{7}{9n - 12}$$

Set the last value should be less than $\epsilon$ and now we have that:

$$\frac{7}{9n - 12} < \epsilon  \iff 9n - 12 > \frac 7\epsilon \iff n > \frac{7 +12 \epsilon}{9\epsilon}$$

So therefore you can choose $n_0 = \frac{7 +12 \epsilon}{9\epsilon}$ and it's not hard do see that this will give you a formal $\epsilon - \delta $ proof.

Comment: So, in this specific case, it is kinda expected of me that I already know that the limit of the sequence is $ \frac{1}{3} $, and that I have to use that fact to solve the problem or could have the problem been solved without me already knowing what the limit of the sequence is? Would I have to try and guess the L then or?

Comment: @FarukČamdžić Well you have to find $frac 13$ and in general the limiting value on your own. One way to do so is to plug some big numbers and make an educated guess about it. Also you can use that:

$$\lim a_n = \lim_{n \to \inf} \frac{n + 1}{3n-4} = \lim_{n \to \inf} \frac{1 + \frac 1n}{3 - \frac 4n} = \frac 13$$

Where you can use the fact that $\lim_{n \to \inf}  \frac cn = 0$. This is an acceptable proof of the claim, but if you want more rigorous proof you should do the $\epsilon - \delta$ proof. But you can still use this method to get the limit value.

Comment: @FarukČamdžić You can use polynomial division to create a fraction where the numerator has lower degree than the denominator. So $n+1=\frac 13 (3n-4)+\frac 73$

Comment: @Stefan4024 You need $3n+3-3n+4$ in your first calculation, to give numerator $7$ rather than $5$.